# PHP create MIME message for Gmail API

Tags: php, gmail

I'm trying to send email via the Gmail API using PHP. The documentation says I need to create a MIME message, encode the entire thing as a base64url string, and then set this string as the 'raw' property of the `Google_Service_Gmail_Message`.

What is the best way in PHP to create this MIME message? I'm also using Laravel 5.1 in case anyone knows of a convenient way to do it using Laravel.  Here is the documentation I'm referring to for the Gmail API:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got this working using the underlying Swift Mailer that comes with Laravel:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setTo(['test@example.com'=>'Test Name']);
$message->setBody('Here is my body');
$message->setSubject('Here is my subject');
echo $message->toString();
```

This outputs:

```
Message-ID: 
Date: Mon, 07 Dec 2015 02:38:30 +0000
Subject: Here is my subject
From: 
To: Test Name 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Here is my body
```

Answer (score 4):

I got it working.., using **imap_mail_compose**

```
 string imap_mail_compose ( array $envelope , array $body )
```

example-1 @: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail-compose.php

```
 $envelope["from"]= "foo@gmail.com";
 $envelope["to"]  = "foo3@example.com";
 $envelope["cc"]  = "bar@example.com";
 $envelope["subject"]  = "Testing..";

 $part1["type"] = TYPETEXT;
 $part1["subtype"] = "plain";
 $part1["description"] = "description3";
 $part1["contents.data"] = "contents.data3\n\n\n\t";

 $body[1] = $part1;

 $mime = imap_mail_compose ($envelope , $body);
 $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($mime), '+/', '-_'), '=');
 $message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
 $message->setRaw($mime);
 $service->users_messages->send($userId, $message);
```

Comment: Make sure you base64urlencode not just base64encode or you will run into errors.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite an old post, but I found it on Google and I've just come across the same problem using Laravel 5.5, this is the way I've done it - just in case it helps anyone :)

The function below will return a HTML string using a blade template that will allow you to pass it into the Google API.

```
/**
 * Create a Message from an email formatted string.
 *
 * @return Google_Service_Gmail_Message Message containing email.
 */
function createMessage()
{
    $message = new \Google_Service_Gmail_Message();

    // Initialise the Swift Message instance.
    $swift = (new Swift_Message())
        ->setSubject('Test Email')
        ->setFrom(['example@example.com' => 'Joe Bloggs'])
        ->setTo(['other@example.com' => 'An Other'])
        ->setBody(view('mail.invoice'), 'text/html')

        // Optionally add any attachments
        ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('my-document.pdf'));

    $message->setRaw(strtr(base64_encode($swift->toString()), array('+' => '-', '/' => '_')));

    return $message;
}
```

If you'd like more information about using SwiftMailer, you can head over to the Symfony website for more info - this is the page I used for this. https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

[Swiftmailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html) can do all the heavy lifting for you, including the Base64 parsing.

```
$service = new \Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$mailer = $service->users_messages;

$message = (new \Swift_Message('Here is my subject'))
    ->setFrom('myemailaddress@myserver.com')
    ->setTo(['receiver@someserver.com'=>'Test Name'])
    ->setContentType('text/html')
    ->setCharset('utf-8')
    ->setBody('<h4>Here is my body</h4>');

$msg_base64 = (new \Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder_Base64ContentEncoder())
    ->encodeString($message->toString());

$message = new \Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$message->setRaw($msg_base64);
$message = $mailer->send('me', $message);
print_r($message);
```

Answer (score 1):

I create mime message from strings as you can see below. Make your own function if you want.

I encoded subject and message with `base64_encode` and put `=?utf-8?B?` to the starting point and `?=` to the end of each one.

```
$mimeMessage  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$mimeMessage  = "From: Fullname <from@from.com>\r\n";
$mimeMessage .= "To: Fullname <to@t.com>\r\n";
$mimeMessage .= "Subject: =?utf-8?B?".base64_encode('Sample Subject Which Contains Non-Latin Characters')."?=\r\n";
$mimeMessage .= "Date: ".date(DATE_RFC2822)."\r\n";
$mimeMessage .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=test\r\n\r\n";
$mimeMessage .= "--test\r\n";
$mimeMessage .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$mimeMessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
$mimeMessage .= base64_encode('Sample email message which contains non-latin chcracters')."\r\n";
```

Be careful while using line breaks. Some lines need `\r\n\r\n`

Then, encode the entire `$mimeMessage` as Gmail API requested:

```
$mimeMessageEncoded = base64url_encode($mimeMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try **PhpMimeClient** and create mime message with attachments and inline images: 
https://github.com/breakermind/PhpMimeParser/blob/master/PhpMimeClient_class.php

Simple example:

```
$m = new PhpMimeClient();

// Add files inline
$m->addFile('photo.jpg',"zenek123");

// Add file
$m->addFile('sun.png');

// create mime
$m->createMime("Witaj księżniczko Alabambo",'<h1>Witaj księżniczko Alabambo <img src="cid:zenek123"> </h1>',"Wesołych świąt życzę!","Heniek Wielki", "heik@dom-ain.com","ho@gomail.coc");

// get mime
// $m->getMime()

// Show mime in browser
echo nl2br(htmlentities($m->getMime()));
```